# So useNavigate is not recommended at all?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom

I see in https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate at "It's usually better to use redirect in loaders and actions than this hook" So should I change useNavigate to redirect instead right ?

Answer (score 2):

> So should I change useNavigate to redirect instead right?

No, not at all. Use the `useNavigate` hook, and returned `navigate` function to issue imperative navigation actions just as it's *always* been done/used in `react-router-dom@6` since it was introduced.

`react-router-dom@6.4.0` introduced many new features relying on the new router creators that add much more functionality to the behavior of the routing context, specifically the [new data APIs](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.0/routers/picking-a-router#using-v64-data-apis). In this specific case it's informing you that you ***shouldn't*** try using the `useNavigate` hook in a [loader](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.0/route/loader). Loaders are functions called by the router to make some asynchronous data request for resources that are passed to the route's component. Only use [`redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.0/fetch/redirect) in the loaders, not `navigate`.